# Is scraping from public Facebook pages legal?

Tags: screen-scraping

**My question is**: Is scraping from public Facebook pages legal ?

**Why am I asking that question** : To get the rating of facebook pages that we don't own using the graph API we will need a page access token, and that is impossible (because the pages that I am talking about are not mine). For that reason I am thinking about scraping the rating of these pages (using Python/Beautiful Soup)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a legal question, not a programming question.

Comment: rule of thumb: if you can´t get it with the graph api (which is the case for ratings), you are not allowed to get it at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scraping Facebook breaks the ToS.
https://www.facebook.com/legal/terms in 
Section 2: Safety
`#2: You will not collect users' content or information, or otherwise access Facebook, using automated means (such as harvesting bots, robots, spiders, or scrapers) without our prior permission.`

So I wouldn't try it. If they consider it 'stealing' information (and I believe they would), they could come after you, as this data is how they make their income.

Comment: Thank you hopperj !

Comment: What about now? the only thing  i can find now is ```You may not access or collect data from our Products using automated means (without our prior permission) or attempt to access data you do not have permission to access.```  Does this apply to auto-comment-reply bots? obviously the bot reads the comment to get suitable answer.