# Scraping img class from facebook HTML source?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I wish to scrape photo links from a facebook's html code. It is given as:

```
<img class="_7jys img" src="https://scontent-arn2-2.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t39.16868-6/s600x600/70767091_398966137483846_5448404540279750656_n.jpg?_ncx" alt="">
```

I am trying to do:

```
url = 'https://www.facebook.com/ads/archive/render_ad/?'

response = requests.get(url, timeout=5)
content = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

garbage = []

for item in content.findAll('src', attrs={'class': 'img' }):
    print(item)
    garbage.append(item.text)
```

It returns an empty list. How do I access the tag?

Comment: [Is scraping from public Facebook pages legal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38772604/215552)...

Comment: See this article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43982002/extract-src-attribute-from-img-tag-using-beautifulsoup/47166671

Comment: To add to the previous comments, it's likely you're hitting one of Facebook's security mechanisms that's in place to prevent this activity (which, to re-iterate, is a violation of their Terms of Service).