# How to retrieve all my friends and my friends' friends on Facebook?

Tags: javascript, python, facebook

I would like to retrieve all my friends, and all of their friends on facebook. From what I understand via the facebook api this isn't possible because I would need all of my friends to accept permission for me to read their friends list? This is kind of strange because if I simply go to the UI and go to a friends 'friend list', I can see their friends, and keep going for all those friends who have their friends list available publicly.

If I can't do this from the API, can I somehow do this with javascript in the console? Or some web scraping just because the info is all there on the UI, I just want to automate it.

Thanks

Comment: there is no way, i am afraid - and scraping is not allowed.

Comment: If you use `selenium` with firefox or chrome (and a proper header), this gets really close to a normal user browsing facebook ([an answer about their ToS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38772604/is-scraping-from-public-facebook-pages-legal)). You will often face problems when webscraping in headless mode, since many things simply don't load. You won't have these problems with `selenium`.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate, because the OP asks for other programming languages, than in the "duplicate".

Comment: _“This is kind of strange”_ - no, it is not. There is a huge difference between _you_ having access to this information via the UI, and any app getting access on your behalf. The latter would mean, the app developer now has access to all that information, too. And _usually_, app developer and app user aren’t the same person.